# Unable to connect Django 2.0.7 with oracle 12c using cx_oracle 6.4 in python 3.7

Tags: python, django, oracle12c, cx-oracle, django-2.0

I am facing a problem in connecting  **Orace 12c** with **Django 2**

command used: `python manage.py migrate`

below is the error message i m getting

```
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator.IP22\Envs\dell\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\Administrator.IP22\Envs\dell\lib\site- packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py", line 497, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
cx_Oracle.ProgrammingError: positional and named binds cannot be intermixed`
```

[click here to see error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxajh.jpg)

Following code is used in settings.py for database

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
    'NAME': 'orcl',
    'USER': 'C##',
    'PASSWORD': 'Oracle_1',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
}
}
```

here is the code for the file 0002_remove_content_type_name.py:

```
from django.db import migrations, models


def add_legacy_name(apps, schema_editor):
ContentType = apps.get_model('contenttypes', 'ContentType')
for ct in ContentType.objects.all():
    try:
        ct.name = apps.get_model(ct.app_label, ct.model)._meta.object_name
    except LookupError:
        ct.name = ct.model
    ct.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

dependencies = [
    ('contenttypes', '0001_initial'),
]

operations = [
    migrations.AlterModelOptions(
        name='contenttype',
        options={'verbose_name': 'content type', 'verbose_name_plural': 'content types'},
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='contenttype',
        name='name',
        field=models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.RunPython(
        migrations.RunPython.noop,
        add_legacy_name,
        hints={'model_name': 'contenttype'},
    ),
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='contenttype',
        name='name',
    ),
]
```

Comment: Your connection works. The error raises during the execution of a query. Would be interesting to see what the contenttypes.0002_remove-content_type_name migration looks like

Comment: There seems to be a [bug in cx_oracle introduced in 6.4](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/199). Apparently, this was not present in 6.3.1, so downgrading could be an option. Or, wait for 6.4.1

Comment: i have added the file 0002_remove_content_type_name.py code in my post

Comment: Thanks, but I really think the issue lies with the mentioned cx_Oracle 6.4 bug I linked in my second comment. Is it possible for you to downgrade to cx_Oracle 6.3.1 and try it with that version?

Answer (score 0):

That issue is due to a [bug](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/199) introduced in cx_Oracle 6.4. If you can build from source you can grab the latest code which has the bug fixed. Or you can wait until cx_Oracle 6.4.1 is released (likely in a few days).

Comment: Anthony has released cx_Oracle 6.4.1.